# IEEE LaTeX style: grouping references

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

I'm writing a paper in LaTeX with the IEEE style and when citing multiple references with `\cite{ref_A,ref_B,ref_C}`, it produces [1],[2],[3]. How can I change that to [1,2,3]?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211777/ieee-latex-style-grouping-references?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Does the the publication venue allow you to make this change to the standard IEEE style?

Comment: Are you sure you want `[1, 2, 3]`? IEEE in fact needs `[1]--[3]`.

Comment: IEEE style with non-IEEE templates ([1]-[3], i.e. multiple cite with separate brackets) can be achieved like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340927/178758

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that you are using the Transactions style with

```
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran} %or draft etc.
```

Using the following line in the preamble

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

and also using the house style of `IEEEtran` with

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

passed the IEEE check more than once.

Comment: Note that this does not generate [1,2,3] but [1]-[3] (which is good, though, as it is in line with the IEEE style guide).

Answer (score 14):

Is your work meant for IEEE transactions? The *IEEEtran* class says:

Citations are made with the `\cite` command as usual. *IEEEtran* will produce citation numbers that are individually bracketed in IEEE style. (“[1], [5]” as opposed to the more
common “[1, 5]” form.) The base *IEEEtran* does not sort or produce compressed “ranges” when there are three or more adjacent citation numbers. However, *IEEEtran* pre-defines
some format control macros to facilitate easy use with Donald Arseneau’s cite.sty package. So, all an author has to do is to call cite.sty.

Answer (score 10):

IEEE has redefined the `\citepunct` macro, which determines what is inserted between citations. You can see this by using the `\citen` command, which doesn't insert the surrounding brackets, instead of `\cite`.

You can redefine this back to the standard comma, penalty and thin space as follows:

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\renewcommand{\citepunct}{,\penalty\citepunctpenalty\,}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}% optionally
```

I don't know if IEEE publication venues are okay with this change or not.

To control the appearance of three or more references, you may have to change the `\citedash` command as well. I haven't played with this, see the reference below for information about the `\cite` command.

Source: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cite/cite.pdf

Answer (score 6):

go to IEEEtran.cls and replace `\def\citepunct{],[}` and `\def\citedash{]--[}` with `\def\citepunct{,}` and `\def\citedash{--}`, respectively. This is if you intend to use the IEEEtrans class in a custom citation format, understanding that it is not suitable for IEEE conferences.

Comment: This is the only answer that works right away. Using `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`, `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`, and `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what marco package you're using, but if your bib style is something like "ieeetr" or "phaip".And it will works.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mcite} Optional if you want mcite feature.
\begin{document}
Insulator\cite{ref1,ref2} does not conduct electricity.
\bibliography{mydata}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

and mydata.bib is:

```
@ARTICLE{ref1,
AUTHOR = "Zdzislaw Pawlak",
TITLE = "Rough sets",
JOURNAL = "International Journal of Computer Infomation Science",
YEAR = "1982",
volume = "5",
pages = "341-356",
}

@ARTICLE{ref2,
AUTHOR = "Zdzislaw Pawlak Jr.",
TITLE = "Rough sets",
JOURNAL = "International Journal of Computer Infomation Science",
YEAR = "1982",
volume = "5",
pages = "341-356",
}
```

Here is example from a tutorial
from [latex editor(In Chinese)](http://zzg34b.w3.c361.com/package/reference-2.htm)

> [image: Input code]
>
> Output:
>
> [image: Tex output]

And this is the [example reference](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/phaip.pdf) of phaip style

BTW, maybe you should go to the [Tex stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for help.

Comment: Where did you get these images from? Please **provide sources**.