# IEEE multiple reference citation style with memoir class

Tags: memoir, natbib

IEEE wants each of a reference in separate brackets (like this: [1],[3]-[5]). How can I achieve this style with memoir class?

I used cite and natbib packages but I get [1,3-5] instead of [1],[3]-[5]....

Ex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,oneside,openbib]{memoir}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
as in \cite{ref1,ref3,ref4,ref5}
\end{document}
```

and I get:

> as in [1,3-5]

instead of:

> as in [1],[3]-[5]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have so far.

Comment: If this is for IEEE, shouldn't you be using one of their document classes?

Comment: It's not for IEEE, but I need IEEE citation style. In fact it's a thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, using `\citenumfont` to set brackets around each number and using `\setcitestyle` to kill the outermost brackets that would otherwise be placed around the whole group.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,oneside,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\setcitestyle{open={},close={}}
\def\citenumfont#1{[#1]}

\begin{document}

As in
\cite{article-minimal,incollection-minimal,manual-full,booklet-full}.

\nocite{booklet-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked well until I needed `\citep[p.~18]{article-minimal}`, i.e., a page/comment. In this case, this yields "[1], p. 18" instead of "[1, p.18]" :(
One could use `\setcitestyle{open={},close={]},citesep={],},notesep={,~}}` and `\def\citenumfont#1{[#1}` instead, but then again this doesn't work when citing multiple sources with compression turned on. It becomes "[3-[5]" instead of "[3]-[5]". It is not possible to change the compression character "--" to "{]}--" to hot-fix this since it is hardcoded in natbib.dtx like this: `\def@NAT@last@yr{--\NAT@penalty}%`